# How to get Button value and set it in input in angular/ionic

Tags: html, angular

I have this `html`button:

```
<button ion-button class="button icon ion-home" round (click)="getColor()" id="one">0</button>
```

I need to get the value('0' in this case) of this button when it is clicked.

here is my `angular` code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  getColor() { 
    document.getElementById("one").nodeValue="0";

  }

}
```

I really tried for many hours to get this right but I couldn't. I'm new to `angular`. Someone please help me with this thing?

Comment: Why you cannot simply pass the 0 to getColor() click handler?

Comment: How do I do that? @RobYed

Comment: (click)="getColor()" will simple be (click)="getColor(0)". Of course, your getColor method then has to expect a parameter. The parameter's value is 0 in your case.

Comment: I edit my answer, see if it's solves the issue now

Answer (score 1):

In Html

```
<button ion-button class="button icon ion-home" round (click)="getColor()" id="one">{{value}}</button>
```

In Angular

```
export class HomePage {
  value: number = 0;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  getColor() { 
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

First define variable in Component then use it in html. This way you will be able to access it easily.

Comment: Can I use button value and set it to `input` ?

Comment: you can use [(ngModel)]="inputValue" attribute in input. Then in getColor set this.value = this.inputValue; Also don't forget to import ngModel

Answer (score 0):

/*********

**EDIT : **

I added the setting of the input value with the button text.

**********/

**using ElementRef and ViewChild is one way**

> **ElementRef**
>   - is the most basic abstraction. If you observe it’s class structure, you’ll see that it only holds the native element it’s associated with. It’s useful for accessing native DOM element
>
> //
>
> **@ViewChild** - 
>   Angular provides a mechanism called DOM queries. It comes in a form of @ViewChild decorator. 
>   You can use ViewChild to get
>   the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view
>   DOM.

from the doc ..

basically assing to an element in your html code 'id' (but in the angular way - not id="...") somthing like #someId,
than you can access that element object using

```
@ViewChild('someId') myElement: ElementRef
```

can read about it here [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

the code:

```
 <button #btn
      ion-button class="button icon ion-home" round 
      (click)="getColor()">
      0
 </button>
 <ion-input #myInput></ion-input>
```

// ==================

```
 import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

 import { NavController, TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

      @ViewChild('btn') btn: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: TextInput;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
      getColor() { 
           const btnText = this.btn.nativeElement.textContent;
           this.myInput.value = btnText; // here you set the value of the
                                         // input to the text on your button
      }
 }
```

// =============================================================//

**author approach, send the HTML object as a parameter to the function you call on (click)**

```
 <button #btn
      ion-button class="button icon ion-home" round 
      (click)="getColor(btn)">
      0
 </button>
 <ion-input #myInput></ion-input>
```

// =====================

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

      @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: TextInput;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
      getColor(myBtn: HTMLButtonElement) { 
            this.myInput.value = myBtn.innerHTML;
      }

 }
```

// =============================================================//

**one more way, maybe the most simplistic is with property binding.**

bind the'value' property of ion-input with class member.

```
 <button #btn
      ion-button class="button icon ion-home" round 
      (click)="getColor(btn)">
      0
 </button>
 <ion-input [value]="inputValue"></ion-input>
```

// =====================

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

      inputValue: string = "";

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
      getColor(myBtn: HTMLButtonElement) { 
            this.inputValue = myBtn.innerHTML;
      }

 }
```

Comment: What is `ViewChild`? Please provide a complete and clean answer

Comment: and it says `cannot read property 'text content' of undefined`

Comment: Hellooooo???? Stil I'm getting this error. **cannot read property 'text content' of undefined**

Comment: did you used it on ionViewDidLoad() ? you can access it only after the view as been load

Comment: i edited the answer, setting the input value to the button text

Comment: @Ofir G ViewChild was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I'm reusing views for crud activity and needed to change button text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $event property which will contain information about the clicked element, presumably `$event.target`:

In your HTML:

```
(click)="getColor($event)"
```

In your TS file:

```
getColor ($event: any) {
    // debug the value of $event
}
```

Or use the method @RobYed provided by passing "0" as the argument.